# Can someone explain something for me about ASP?

Tags: database, asp

I need to explain Database (ASP with Database back end) as part of my pass criteria, but I don't understand how a Database works with ASP.

Cheers in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages).  ASP is basically a programming language built for web-servers.  When you request a resource (like https://serverfault.com/questions), then the ASP script should look up the resources needed in a database.

Parameters can be passed in either through the URL or in the HTTP request header.  The ASP script then determines what data is needed by the client and provides that information.  In this way, a page can be static or data can be loaded on the fly using AJAX.

It basically works like this:

- Client requests a resource
- Server interprets the request
- Server asks the database for some information
- Server gives the client what was requested (HTML, media, RSS feeds, etc)

All web-servers work in the same manner.  The only difference is that ASP runs on Microsoft's .NET framework, so it works better with Microsoft products like Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thank you for clearing that up, best answer :)

Comment: Indeed :), I just needed to wait 5 minutes for permission ;p

Comment: Hahaha, alright. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I suggest you go back and either tell the professor he is an idiot, or realize that "not learning but have other people provide you with your homework" does not make you someone who knows.

One hint, though - a database works with ASP as it does WITH ANY OTHER CLIENT. Your question is analogues to say "I dont nuderstand how a light switch works in a car". Like any other light switch.

Comment: I wasn't so much looking for an answer to plagiarize, just something that can help me advance on how ASP works with a database, It's something I've never understood fully.